# Invalid use of void expression with memcpy in an arbitray sort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of arbitrary type in C. I am using pointers to voids and memcpy. However, I keep getting errors saying 'invalid use of void expression' associated with the memcopy function, and 'invalid dereferencing of void pointers'. I know there are many other threads about this error, but reading those threads hasn't helped me solve the problem. My code is below:

```
#include "mysort.h"
#include <alloca.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mysort(int n, int elementSize, void * array, int ascending,CompareFunction compFunc)
{
    //bubblesort algorithm
    if (ascending == 1) 
    {   int c,d;
        void * swap = malloc(elementSize);
        void * thing1 = malloc(elementSize);
        void * thing2 = malloc(elementSize);

        for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++)
        {
            for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++)
            {
                memcpy(thing1, array[d], elementSize);
                memcpy(thing2, array[d+1], elementSize);
                if ( compFunc(thing1,thing2) >= 0) 
                    {
                        memcpy(swap, array[d], elementSize);
                        array[d] = array[d+1];
                        array[d+1]= swap;
                    }
            }
        }
    }   


    if (ascending != 1) 
    {   int c,d;
        void * swap = malloc(elementSize);
        void * thing1 = malloc(elementSize);
        void * thing2 = malloc(elementSize);

        for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++)
        {
            for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++)
            {
                memcpy(thing1, array[d], elementSize);
                memcpy(thing2, array[d+1], elementSize);
                if ( compFunc(thing1,thing2) <= 0) 
                    {
                        memcpy(swap, array[d], elementSize);
                        array[d] = array[d+1];
                        array[d+1]= swap;
                    }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You just can't dereference a pointer to `void` as you do in `array[d]`

Comment: How should compiler now what type it shoule be dereferenced to? (How many bytes should be used?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, the the compiler is complaining about `array[d]` and `array[d + 1]`.  Parameter `array` is a `void *`, so if those expressions were valid then they would designate objects of type `void`, which cannot exist.

That's just a symptom of the underlying problem, however.  You don't want to pass the array elements to `memcpy()` in the first place.  Instead, you want to pass pointers to them.  The best way to express those is probably via pointer arithmetic.  For example:

```
memcpy(thing1, ((char *) array) + (d * elementSize), elementSize);
```

Comment: thanks! using this method without the pointer to char cast worked

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the array subscript operator on a `void *` the way you would with an array of a known type.  You need to cast to a `char *` and do the pointer arithmetic yourself.

Also, you don't need `thing1` and `thing2`.  Just call `compFunc` directly on the elements you want to compare.

So change this:

```
            memcpy(thing1, array[d], elementSize);
            memcpy(thing2, array[d+1], elementSize);
            if ( compFunc(thing1,thing2) >= 0) 
                {
                    memcpy(swap, array[d], elementSize);
                    array[d] = array[d+1];
                    array[d+1]= swap;
                }
```

To this:

```
            void *current = (char *)array + (elementSize * d);
            void *next = (char *)array + (elementSize * (d + 1));
            if ( compFunc(current, next) >= 0)
                {
                    memcpy(swap, current, elementSize);
                    memcpy(current, next, elementSize);
                    memcpy(next, swap, elementSize);
                }
```

And similarly in the other case.

Comment: Although some compilers accept it, C does not define arithmetic on pointers of type `void *` (because `void` is an incomplete type).  To stay within the standard you need to cast to a pointer to a complete type, such as `char *`, and perform arithmetic on that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks.  Edited.